# Check if window.location.reload is invoked in JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

```
const ErrorSnackbar = () => {

     const handelePrimaryBtnClick = () => { window.location.reload() }

     return ( <div className = 'sample_class' onClick={handelePrimaryBtnClick}> Sample Code </div> )
}
```

In jest How to check if window.location.reload() is invoked when I click on the div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can spy the `reload` method and simulate a click on the `div`, something like:

```
it("should reload the page", () => {
  jest.spyOn(window.location, 'reload');
  const component = mount(ErrorSnackbar());
  component.find('.sample_class').simulate('click');
  expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, I get TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'reload' of object '[object Location]'

Answer (score 1):

With recent `jsdom` implementations, it is not possible to spy on `window.location.reload`, and also it is not configurable:

```js
> console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.location, 'reload'))
{
  value: [Function: reload],
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false
}
```

It cannot be set to non-configurable, so before each test, its parent, `window.location` has to be deleted and replaced with a mock implementation:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  delete window.location;
  window.location = { reload: jest.fn() };
});
```

Then, in the test, we can verify calls:

```js
expect(window.location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Thanks for [this blog](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/11/17/mock-window-location/) for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the suggestion from @gombosg, I wasn't allowed to delete window.location, since it's not an optional field. Solved it with this little "any hack":

```
const windowRef: any = window;
windowRef.location = { ...window.location, reload: jest.fn() };
```

Also, as I was basing the optional redirect on the result of an API call, the (mocked) API call failed in obscure ways when I deleted window.location. This works if I include other functions in the mocked windowRef.location. Took me some time to figure out.